# In excel create new table from mothertable based on filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel I've got a table that tracks a local storage where packages are stored for different companies. Now from this table I would like to create several new tables containing the same information but now these tables are filtered based on company. The information in the main table will be updated continuously so I would like the other tables to do so as well and not have to update them manually.

[image: Example of the table]

So when a package arrives for Company A, a new row will be added to the table of company A with all the information (ID, date of delivery, place in the storage, what it consist of, extra information etc.). And if Company B picks up one item from the storage it can be deleted from the mother table thus removing it from the table of Company B.

My knowledge of excel is limited and I've tried google'ing it but the only option I've found is the `=IFERROR` formula, which seems very complicated for something I thought would be fixed easily. I'd like to know if there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be done with formulas that duplicate the data. Use reporting techniques instead. For example, create ONE report sheet with a pivot table based on the main data table and use filters or slicers to select the data for just a particular company.

When the data in the main table changes, you only need to click the "Refresh All" icon in the ribbon for the pivot table to reflect the changes.

If you are new to pivot tables, take a look around the web. There are plenty of tutorials to help you learn.

Comment: It took some time to work out, but I've got it working. Pivot tables were the way to go. I just didn't know how to use them for this usecase. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can this answer be elaborated on please?  I've been trying to do this with pivot tables for hours and believe this is not possible.  In fact according to this video, you can only hack your way around putting text values into a reporting pivot table - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7_YvOpjUBNQ.  I should mention that I have quite a bit of experience with pivot tables but mostly in Google Sheets where this is quite straight-forward.  I just can't figure out how to do it in Excel pivot tables.

Comment: @Dan you may want to ask your own question, because I can't tell from your comment why this would NOT work for you. Please ask a question and then, if you want,  post a link in a new comment here.

Comment: @teylyn, when you refer to "this", are you referring to the provided answer ("pivot tables") or the video link I provided?

If the former, because the solution wasn't actually provided.  It doesn't state how to do it with pivot tables.

If the latter, because the video link content is a pretty convoluted solution and I'm struggling to believe that this is the best way to do it.  I'm hoping your pivot table solution, once you provide some details, is better.

Comment: @Dan, Yes, with "this" I'm referring to my answer. What do you refer to when you write "Can this answer be elaborated on please? I've been trying to do this with pivot tables"? I should think it were my answer. If it isn't then why post a comment.

Comment: Hi @teylyn.  My comment is pointing out that I believe the answer you've provided doesn't actually have enough details to reproduce and confirm that it solved the original question.  The original question stated that there was one main table and they'd like to create separate tables that contain *the same information* but only for a single company.  I have the same problem and in my research, I've found that this actually *can't* be done with pivot tables.  I would like to know how you did it so I can reconcile our different beliefs. Without the *how*, it shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi @Dan, the asker accepts the answer. The asker has full discretion to do that. If the answer does not work for them, they don't need to accept it. This answer was accepted by the asker, so it must have worked for them. If you need more detailed instructions how to make this answer work (and it totally is doable with pivot tables), then you may want to ask your own question. Feel free to post a link to this answer in your question, for reference. And if you leave a comment here, with a link to your new question, I'll try and take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, @teylyn . I've had a few people confirm my findings now that it can't be done with Excel pivot tables.  I'm satisfied at this point.  Stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to have to go with teylyn here Dan.
The only bit of Kars' question that pivot tables don't automatically do is the "not have to update them manually". Not that right-clicking the pivot table and selecting "Refresh" is a huge issue.

To automate this, all one has to do is add some code to the main data table's sheet via VBA Editor. Whenever one leaves that sheet for another, all pivot tables in the workbook are automatically refreshed.
This is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```